# Change output path of program in bash

Tags: macos, bash, directory, output, portability

I just got a mac, and since I am more used to windows cmd than bash in linux and mac, I am struggling with this.
I am trying to change an output path using bash to make some apps portable.
In cmd, it was something like this

```
Set APPDATA=%CD%/certainfolderforportablestuff
```

How does this work in bash? Just keep the Appdata folder name though.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
APPDATA=%CD%/certainfolderforportablestuff
```

in bash should be

```
APPDATA=$PWD/certainfolderforportablestuff
```

And since you're just starting with bash I suggest that you place variables inside double quotes by default:

```
APPDATA="$PWD/certainfolderforportablestuff"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I made a big mistake here, how do you do the set command in bash? Is it the same?

Comment: You don't need to use Set in Bash. Assignment of variables are simply in the format of `VAR=VALUE`. Check the information about paramaters which include variables here http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters. You can also read the document on your terminal by running `man bash`.